# Thread safety of yield return with Parallel.ForEach()

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, ienumerable, yield-return, parallel.foreach

Consider the following code sample, which creates an enumerable collection of integers and processes it in parallel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(CreateItems(100), item => ProcessItem(item));
    }

    private static IEnumerable<int> CreateItems(int count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }

    private static void ProcessItem(int item)
    {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Is it guaranteed that the worker threads generated by `Parallel.ForEach()` each get a different item or is some locking mechanism around incrementation and returning of `i` required?

Comment: Just use Enumerable.Range there.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: I think, it's just a iterator sample.

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: And how does `Enumerable.Range()` help me with processing an `IEnumerable` in parallel?

Comment: BTW, in this specific case, it would probably make more sense to use `Parallel.For()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Parallel.ForEach<TSource>`, when `TSource` is an `IEnumerable<T>`, creates a partitioner for the `IEnumerable<T>` that includes its own *internal locking mechanism*, so you don't need to implement any thread-safety in your iterator.

Whenever a worker thread requests a chunk of items, the partitioner will create an *internal enumerator*, which:

1. acquires a shared lock
2. iterates through the source (from where it was left of) to retrieve the chunk of items, saving the items in an private array
3. releases the lock so that other chunk requests can be fulfilled.
4. serves the worker thread from its private array.

As you see, the run through the `IEnumerable<T>` for the purposes of partitioning is sequential (accessed via a shared lock), and the partitions are processed in parallel.

Comment: Found this through google, did it, and get told by VS that it can be simplyfied to Parallel.ForEach(...).
Is it possible ForEach has this functionality now regardless of getting told a specific type?

Comment: @MarlonRegenhardt  yes, VS is correct. That simplification feature is called "type inference".  For example, when you type `Parallel.ForEach(myList, ...)`, the c# compiler can "infer" the generic type parameter (`<TSource>`) by looking at the generic type of `myList`.

Answer (score 1):

TPL and PLINQ use the concept of *partitioners*.

Partitioner is a type, that inherits [`Partitioner<TSource>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381768.aspx) and serves for the splitting the source sequence into a number parts (or partitions). Built-in partitioners were designed to split the source sequence into nonoverlapping partitions.

Comment: I think this doesn't actually answer the question: is the code in the question (which, on the surface, doesn't use `Partitioner` at all) thread-safe?

Comment: @svick: the question is "Is it guaranteed that the worker threads generated by Parallel.ForEach() each get a different item". The question isn't about thread-safety of the iterator.