# Conditionally blocking IEnumerable<t> yield return result

Tags: c#, multithreading, ienumerable, yield-return

I'm hoping someone can help me find a more efficient solution to my problem below. I'm using the IEnumerable yield return pattern in a multi-threaded pipeline. Under most conditions this is working great, however, I have some scenarios where I need the operations in the pipeline to occur synchronously instead of in parallel threads to get the correct result. (i.e. running into concurrency issues).

Existing code is:

```
public override IEnumerable<Row> Execute(IEnumerable<Row> rows)
{
    foreach (Row row in rows)
    {
        //do some work....
        yield return row;
    }
}
```

I'm thinking of creating an optional parameter that controls blocking vs. non blocking output of the enumerator; something along the lines of:

```
public override IEnumerable<Row> Execute(IEnumerable<Row> rows, bool BlockingExecution)
{
    if (BlockingExecution)
    {
        return BlockingExecute(rows);
    }
    else
    {
        return NonBlockingExecute(rows);
    }
 }

 private IEnumerable<Row> NonBlockingExecute(IEnumerable<Row> rows)
 {
    foreach (Row row in rows)
    {
        //do some work....
        yield return row;
    }
 }

 private IEnumerable<Row> BlockingExecute(IEnumerable<Row> rows)
 {
     List<Row> BlockingResult = new List<Row>();
     foreach(Row r in NonBlockingExecute(rows))
     {
         BlockingResult.Add(r);
     }
     return BlockingResult;
 }
```

In the BlockingExecute function it seems inefficient to create a copy of the IEnumerable into a List to force the entire pipeline to flush. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Essentially, what you want is to either enumerate over given enumberable `rows` (supposedly returning the results lazily - being referred as non-blocking here), or you want to enumerate over the materialized enumerable, like so, `rows.ToList()`.

Hence, you should be able to use what is already available in the .Net framework.

Comment: Side note: enumerator created via `yield return` is not thread safe, consider proper locking or something like [partitioning with Parallel.ForEach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021779/thread-safety-of-yield-return-with-parallel-foreach)

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say there are concurrency issues. But there's nothing in the code you included that would address concurrency issues. What concurrency issues exist? How do they relate to the enumeration of the collection? In what way does materializing the collection relate to addressing the concurrency issues?

Comment: Hi @peter-duniho, for the full framework of this scenario check out the open source Rhino ETL project: http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/oss/rhino-etl The scenario is as a follows. There are several DBCommand operations chained together in the ETL pipeline. The first one doing an insert operation and the subsequent one performing matching between inserted rows. The matching operation requires all rows to be inserted to get the correct result. Using lazy execution some matches are missed but forcing eager loading of the insert DBCommand to process all rows insures the matching is correct.

Comment: @Andrew: no one wants to see "the full framework". See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You should post a question that is short, but still completely encapsulates the essence of whatever problem you're having. Nothing in your most recent comment explains how materialization of the collection _solves_ any concurrency issue, though it does suggest it's _possible_ you've simply adjusted the execution profile to make them less likely to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, a "blocking execution" will be some degree of inefficient. But I'd probably use `ToArray` for that form, and your non-blocking version is a little confusing. Is it really supposed to do work for each one that the blocking one doesn't?

I would probably do this.

```
public override IEnumerable<Row> Execute(IEnumerable<Row> rows, bool BlockingExecution)
{
    if (BlockingExecution)
    {
        return rows.ToArray();
    }
    else
    {
        return NonBlockingExecute(rows); // or just "return rows". It seems like the best 
                                         // practice here, in most cases anyway
                                         // would be to move that work elsewhere
    }
 }

 private IEnumerable<Row> NonBlockingExecute(IEnumerable<Row> rows)
 {
    foreach (Row row in rows)
    {
        //do some work....
        yield return row;
    }
 }
```

But yes, the blocking version will require multiple iterations of the same list still (one to create the array, one to presumably read it). I'm not sure there's any way to escape that, since you want some way of loading it all into memory.

Comment: "that doesn't do anything more than simply iterating over the enumerable" I assumed it does, at least that's how i interpreted the `//do some work....` comment.

Comment: @svick oh heavens, good point. I totally skipped over that. I've fixed my answer. Thanks for pointing that out.